# OPEN GL ES2.0 3D texture extension is not working

Tags: opengl-es

I am using openGL es2.0 3D texture extension for my  array casting project.
but I have only black screen. There is my texture code.it shows error in GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S_OES and GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T_OES. I don't know how to resolve that.

```
glGenTextures(1,&textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,textureID);

    glTexImage3DOES(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,0,GL_RGB,XDIM,YDIM,ZDIM,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pData);
    // set the texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S_OES,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T_OES,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R_OES,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    //set the mipmap levels (base and max)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL,0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL,4);
    //generate mipmaps
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES);
    //delete the volume data allocated on heap
    delete[]pData;
```

Comment: Sometimes extensions that don't work are advertised. You need to get over it and don't use them.

Comment: `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S_OES` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T_OES` are non-standard tokens, where have you got them and what's their values? `GL_OES_texture_3D` only introduces `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R_OES`, S and T should be without OES suffix.

Comment: thank to you both i think i should switch to opengl es 3.0.

Comment: i tried to fix the errors but still i have an error and i cannot find it out.the error is in this line GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D_OES,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R_OES,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)).whats wrong in this lline of code?